# How to remove default padding/margin from around the email view of outlook for HTML emails

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I'm having some trouble finding away to remove the padding or margin default values from around my html email in most versions of outlook. I was wondering if there is something that I can put into my HTML email to prevent the padding/margin from showing.

Thanks

Comment: style="margin:0;padding:0"

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #252525" bgcolor="#252525">
```

Just note whatever you set the body background color to will bleed into the email chain if it is forwarded. I'd suggest leaving the body white and setting the color on a html container table to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you need for your table cells to be completely flat without padding and empty make sure to add this to the table:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

And in the case of the empty cells

```
    <td style="font-size:0px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS reset from the [HTML Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/):

```
body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.ExternalClass {width:100%;}
```

Or better yet, just use the Boilerplate as the starting point for your e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline styles, that override Outlook's defaults (they have higher precedence).

Eg.

```
<div style="padding:0; margin:0;" class="wrapper">
  ... etc ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Hexblot, but I've already put these styles    style="background:#ebebeb; padding:0px; margin:0px;" onto the body and the containing table

Comment: so if you inspect the styles with Firebug (in Firefox) or Chrome's built in tool, do you see those being overridden? or are Outlook's styles applied on a different level? You might try to bolster your rules with `!important` as a last resort (or if Outlook already uses it).

Comment: It works fine locally in the browser it seems to be outlook has a default padding/margin round it that pushes it 10px aroudn the whole email. see as I want the header of the email to be 100% of all email clients but when it gets to outlook it just gets to the last 10px and shows the background of the body/inside container instead of the content colour. I think this is something that is built into Outlook with further research and nothing I can do about it.