# Microsoft Outlook adding margin to images

Tags: image, email, outlook, margin

First time email creator here, everything works well on my Mac browsers but once I jump into Outlook I run into a few problems.

Outlook (2007, and no doubt other versions) is adding margins around images, some are receiving top and bottom margin, some just top or bottom. I've applied the widths to the images (email size is no bigger than 600px wide) and also tried border="0: on them but no avail. Also made sure I don't have any margins set to my tables (which can take affect on nested TD's).

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574964/3555636
Adding  <td style="font-size:0px;"> did the trick in my case.
Know it's old but maybe someone will get here looking for the same answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007/2010 adds 15px top/bottom and 10px left/right body padding to all html emails. You can't get rid of it.

See [Rich HTML emails in Outlook 2007 and 2010… how do you remove the top margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533240/rich-html-emails-in-outlook-2007-and-2010-how-do-you-remove-the-top-margin) for more information.

Comment: My problem isn't caused on the body element, it can happily go add padding/mragin to the body element its on images, for example I've two images next to each other like so:

    `<tr>
            <td> <!-- MAIN BANNER -->
                <img src="banner.gif" alt="" width="600" height="242" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="divider.gif" width="600" height="3" />
            </td>
        </tr>`

But I am then getting spacing issues between these two images